# how to close dialog box without changing ui in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I have a list of charts in my workspace page and I have Delete confirmation dialog box if I want to delete selected chart.

When delete dialog box is open and when ever I click cancel button on the dialog or click outside the dialog, the selected chart is not deleted but some reason it disappear by it self from the the chart list(UI changed). When I refresh the browser it appear again. I'm not really sure what causing that to happened so I would be really appreciate if someone can help me how to fix this bug by looking at my code.

I just want the chart to stay the same if it's not deleted and only disappear once it's actually deleted.

Workspace Page.HTML

```
// Imported Chart list component like this

<div class="ws-container">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let chart of charts">
      <mc-chart-list [chart]="chart" [editMode]="true" [wsType]="workspace.type" (removeFromList)="onRemoveFromList($event)"></mc-chart-list>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Workspace Page.TS

```
  onRemoveFromList(id: number) {
    const index = this.charts.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.charts.splice(index, 1);
    } }
```

Chart-List.html

```
<button mat-menu-item (click)="deleteChart()"
*ngIf="chart.hasAccess && chart.canEdit && !chart.isPublished">Delete Chart</button>
```

Chart-List.ts

```
  deleteChart() {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteWsDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        chart: this.chart, isChart: true
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.removeFromList.emit(this.chart.id);
 })}
```

Delete-WS-Dialog.HTML

```
    <div mat-dialog-actions class="button">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" mat-dialog-close style="margin-left:100px;">No, I'm still
            working.</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onDeleteClick()" style="margin-left:30px;">Yes, Delete
            it.</button>
    </div>
```

It's not gonna run but I've uploaded the full code for those three component in stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a1uaqj . Thank you

Comment: check the value of result in `afterClosed().subscribe` prior delete or not the item

Comment: hi @Eliseo I check the value and it said undefined. not sure what is going on and how to fix this

Comment: the method `close` allow an argument, so you can write,e.g. `this.dialogRef.close(true)` if workspace it's sucessfullt deleted, `this.dialogRef.close(false)` if workspace  can not be deleted, and `this.dialogReg.close()` in the rest of case. Then you received true,false or null in response

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteChart` function which launches the dialog also removes the chart when the dialog is closed. But you are not checking the result of the dialog response. You need to provide a response value when closing the dialog, and check whether the user chose yes or no before deleting the chart. For Example:

In the dialog template, assign a default 'no' value to `mat-dialog-close`:

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="false">No, I'm still working.</button>
```

In the dialog code, pass a value into the dialog ref's close function:

```
onNoClick(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close(false); // pass false to indicate a 'no' response
}

onDeleteClick(): void {
  ...
  this.dialogRef.close(true); // pass true to indicate a 'yes' response
  ...
}
```

In the main code, check for confirmation:

```
deleteChart() {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteWsDialogComponent, {
    data: {
      chart: this.chart, isChart: true
    }
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {

    // check for user confirmation
    if (result) {
      this.removeFromList.emit(this.chart.id);
    }
  })
}
```